# Deciding whether to embed or externally save my code

Tags: java, html, css, embed

I've made a code which displays an array which shows traffic lights flashing, should I save externally as script files or embed it into the HTML.

I also need to explain why I've done this.

Please I've got until over Christmas to finish this, I've looked everywhere and can't find much, so I'm turning to this where apparently experienced programmers are and who have done all this before.

Please don't close the question, I really need help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the ultimate goal?

- Code maintainability - use external script
- Reuseability - use external script
- Downloadtime/network i/o - a bit better if embedded.
- Want the HTML/CSS redone by designer later - use external script

The more I think of it, the more reasons I see to put it extern.

And tge one I listed pro embed - that's nullified at second load (script from cache)

Answer (score 0):

Revering to the [MVC-Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) I'd put it in an extra file. It's just better structured and better to read.

Another advantage is that you can reuse your code. Like if you'd have a second page which uses this code you would just need the include it there, too.